# Highlight current sidebar item - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the current sidebar item highlighted, i used this code:

```
<ul class="app-menu">
        <li><a class="app-menu__item" href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a class="app-menu__item" href="#">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a class="app-menu__item" href="@Url.Action("Index","Stock")">Stock</a></li>
        <li><a class="app-menu__item" href="@Url.Action("Index","Article")">Article</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    $(".app-menu li a").click(function () {
        $(".app-menu li a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

But this code isn't working. what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove **"**...**"** and use **'**...**'** :

```
 <li><a class="app-menu__item" href="@Url.Action('Index','Home')">Accueil</a></li>
```

Comment: Same problem persists

Comment: sorry but gotta ask, have you included jQuery script in your html ?

Comment: Yes i have included it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code, I think there is a problem with your href link

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  
  <style>
    .app-menu a.app-menu__item.active {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#333;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
<ul class="app-menu">
        <li><a class="app-menu__item" href="@Url.Action('Index','Home')">Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a class="app-menu__item" href="#">Categories</a></li>
        <li><a class="app-menu__item" href="@Url.Action('Index','Stock')">Stock</a></li>
        <li><a class="app-menu__item" href="@Url.Action('Index','Article')">Article</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(".app-menu li a").click(function () {
        $(".app-menu li a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
</script>



</body>

</html>
```